# How to create Table of Contents in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

How can I add a Table of Contents to a Keynote presentation that shows pages and titles in some hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that in any presentation software I've used.  Presentations do not lend themselves to the need of a table of conents, as they are meant to go through slide-by-slide.  What is your use case for a TOC is presentation?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey: I could see myself needing a TOC for a presentation as well: as part of the introduction and a guide for the viewer — "what will be part of this presentation?"

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey scientific presentations often present an overview. The LaTeX Beamer package can make one for you automatically.

Comment: I consider it a professionnal practice to put a *small* TOC in any long presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one is using **Keynote 6** (OP did not state version used.), one way to create a Table of Contents or Handout is to use the **Print** dialog.

This can be printed to PDF for handouts.  One way to customize would be to create a duplicate copy of your presentation then edit the copy before printing the outline.

**Edit** After printing the outline to PDF, one can create a new slide at the beginning of the presentation and insert the PDF outline onto the slide.

[image: Print dialog]

Answer (score 1):

So far, this is the best solution I've found, and AppleScript:
http://gingerbbm.com/2012/08/keynote-table-of-contents/

To get it working, save your keynote document in your "Documents" folder and update the script with your documents' name.

Make sure you check out the comments at the bottom, I've described how to make the ToC work with your Slide's titles (as opposed to slide notes, which are the default).

If you have a more recent version of Keynote than the one mentioned in the gingerbbm.com article, you can look at the [AppleScript and Keynote](https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/index.html) pages over at macosxautomation.com